# jQuery - Stop form submit depending on ajax response, otherwise let it submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I setup some jQuery code so that when a user tries to submit this form, it checks to see what the ajax response is from our 'check_bid_locked' function in php. If it's 'assigned', 'expired', or 'yes', then it uses e.prevent_default() to stop the submit and show a modal popup message (which is working).

What I can't seem to figure out is how to let the form be SUBMITTED if the response doesn't match any of these. Basically, if the response is 'no' then we want the form to be submitted. Any ideas?

HTML

```
    <form onsubmit="return true check_submits();" method="post" action="<?php echo get_permalink($pid); ?>"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="control_id" value="<?php echo base64_encode($pid); ?>" /> 
   <input class="submit_bottom" id="submits_crt" type="submit" name="bid_now_reverse" value="<?php _e("Place Bid",'BidTheme'); ?>" />
  </form>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready("#bid_now_reverse").submit(function(e) {

var allowSubmit = false;
if (allowSubmit == false) {
e.preventDefault();
}

    var data = {
        'action': 'check_bid_locked',
        'pid': <?php echo $pid; ?>,
        'uid': <?php echo $uid; ?>
    };

    jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>', data, 
function(response) {
            //If bid NOT locked
            if(response == 'no') {
            allowSubmit == true;
            }
            //If Assigned
            if(response == 'assigned') {
            confirm('<div class="bid_panel_box_title">Task Has Been 
Assigned</div><div class="padd10_center">Your offer can\'t be deleted.
</div>', {
                    /* 
                    Define your buttons here, can handle multiple buttons 
                    with custom title and values
                    */
                    buttons: [
                        { class: "delete_button15", type: "button", title: 
"Close", value: "Cancel" }

                    ],
                    modal: true
                }, 
                //Reload page START
                function(resp) {
                   console.log(resp);
            if(resp == 'Cancel'){
                window.location.reload(true);
            } } 
            //Reload page END
        );                  
        //If Expired
    }else if(response == 'expired'){
        confirm('<div class="bid_panel_box_title">Task Has Expired</div><div class="padd10_center">Your offer can\'t be deleted.</div>', {
                /* 
                Define your buttons here, can handle multiple buttons 
                with custom title and values
                */
                buttons: [
                    { class: "delete_button15", type: "button", title: "Close", value: "Cancel" }

                ],
                modal: true
            }, 
            //Reload page START
            function(resp) {
               console.log(resp);
        if(resp == 'Cancel'){
            window.location.reload(true);
        } } 
            //Reload page END
        );
        //If Change Offer Locked
    }else if(response == 'yes'){
    allowSubmit = false;
        confirm('<div class="bid_panel_box_title">Offer Change Locked</div><div class="padd10_center">The Poster is reviewing your offer.<br/><br/>Check back shortly to see if it was accepted or to change it.</div>', {
                /* 
                Define your buttons here, can handle multiple buttons 
                with custom title and values
                */
                buttons: [
                    { class: "delete_button15", type: "button", title: "Close", value: "Cancel"}

                ],
                modal: true
            }, 
            //Reload page START
            function(resp) {
               console.log(resp);
        if(resp == 'Cancel'){
            window.location.reload(true);
        } } 
            //Reload page END
        );
        } 
});
```

});

Comment: You should check at the end of the function. This way `if (allowSubmit == false)` will always be true.

Comment: I put this at the end of the function but the form will still submit even when the response is "assigned", "expired" or "yes" which is when I don't want it to submit.

Comment: `$(document).ready("#bid_now_reverse").submit(function(e) {` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -1):

Use `submit` :

```
if(response == 'no'){
    $('form').submit();
}
```

Comment: When I use this, the form will still not submit for some reason.

Comment: what is the `response`? is it `"no"`?

Comment: Yes, the response where we WANT the form to submit is 'no'.

The responses we DON'T want the form to submit are 'assigned', 'expired', and 'yes'.

Comment: Okay but is that what you're getting back from the server?

Comment: Yes it is. I did a test to make sure, by showing a message if the response is 'no', and this works without issue.

Comment: what is the function `check_submits()`?

Comment: This function just checks a few things in the actual submit field to make sure they don't try to submit an empty value, the length, etc. I've added the function above for you to see.

Comment: on your `form` tag, remove the `onsubmit` attribute. let's see what happens

Comment: When I keep the onsubmit attribute and try to submit with the ajax response 'no', the form will not submit. When I remove the onsubmit attribute with the ajax response 'no', the form still submits. 

The e.preventDefault() that I have at the beginning after document.ready is what's stopping this from submitting, but if I remove it, then the form will submit no matter what the response is. I ONLY want the form to submit if the response is 'no'.

Comment: remove the `onsubmit` from the form, keep the `e.preventDefault()`, and also include the code snippet that I wrote as my answer.

Comment: I've added my new code above but it still will not submit if the ajax response is 'no'.

Comment: inside the if block for `response == 'no'`, add this line `console.log('response is no');` and let me know what happens

Comment: When I change the if statement so console.log is under the form.submit like so: 
$('form').submit();
console.log('response is no');
and try to submit, nothing happens still.

Comment: place it above the form submit and then check your console

Comment: The console gives me the message 'response is no', so I know the response is correct. If I put $('form').submit(); below this, then I get a Jquery error in console of "jquery.js:4 POST https://www.mywebsiteaddress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 504 ()" and the form won't submit.

Answer (score -1):

Because it was asked, here's the check_submits function. It's basically just used when a form is submitted, to make sure a user isn't trying to submit a blank entry, it checks the length, etc.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function check_submits()
{

if(jQuery("#days_done").length > 0)
if( jQuery("#days_done").val() == '' ) 
{
    alert("<?php _e('Please type in the number of days.','ProjectTheme'); ?>");
    return false;   
}

if( jQuery("#bid").val() == '' ) 
{
    alert("<?php _e('Please type in a bid value.','ProjectTheme'); ?>");
    return false;   
}

else if( jQuery("#bid").val().length > 4 ) 
{
    alert("Offer Amount should not be more than 4 digits");
    return false;   
}

return true;
}



</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

As per the suggestions so far, this is what I've changed my code to but it still will not submit if the ajax response is 'no'.

HTML

```
<form id="submit_offer"  method="post" action="<?php echo get_permalink($pid); ?>"> 
<input class="submit_bottom" id="submits_crt" type="submit" name="bid_now_reverse" value="<?php _e("Place Bid",'ProjectTheme'); ?>" />
</form>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready("#bid_now_reverse").submit(function(e) {

    var data = {
        'action': 'check_bid_locked',
        'pid': <?php echo $pid; ?>,
        'uid': <?php echo $uid; ?>
    };

    e.preventDefault();

        jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>', data, function(response) {
            //If offer NOT locked then allow form to submit
            if(response == 'no'){
            $('form').submit();
            //If Assigned
            }else if(response == 'assigned') {
            confirm('<div class="bid_panel_box_title">Task Has Been Assigned</div><div class="padd10_center">Your offer can\'t be deleted.</div>', {
                    /* 
                    Define your buttons here, can handle multiple buttons 
                    with custom title and values
                    */
                    buttons: [
                        { class: "delete_button15", type: "button", title: "Close", value: "Cancel" }

                    ],
                    modal: true
                }, 
                //Reload page START
                function(resp) {
                   console.log(resp);
            if(resp == 'Cancel'){
                window.location.reload(true);
            } } 
                //Reload page END
            );              
            //If Expired
        }else if(response == 'expired'){
            confirm('<div class="bid_panel_box_title">Task Has Expired</div><div class="padd10_center">Your offer can\'t be deleted.</div>', {
                    /* 
                    Define your buttons here, can handle multiple buttons 
                    with custom title and values
                    */
                    buttons: [
                        { class: "delete_button15", type: "button", title: "Close", value: "Cancel" }

                    ],
                    modal: true
                }, 
                //Reload page START
                function(resp) {
                   console.log(resp);
            if(resp == 'Cancel'){
                window.location.reload(true);
            } } 
                //Reload page END
            );
            //If Change Offer Locked
        }else if(response == 'yes'){
            confirm('<div class="bid_panel_box_title">Offer Change Locked</div><div class="padd10_center">The Poster is reviewing your offer.<br/><br/>Check back shortly to see if it was accepted or to change it.</div>', {
                    /* 
                    Define your buttons here, can handle multiple buttons 
                    with custom title and values
                    */
                    buttons: [
                        { class: "delete_button15", type: "button", title: "Close", value: "Cancel"}

                    ],
                    modal: true
                }, 
                //Reload page START
                function(resp) {
                   console.log(resp);
            if(resp == 'Cancel'){
                window.location.reload(true);
            } } 
                //Reload page END
            );
            }       
    });
});
```